# Transferring a value between two tables where one field is %LIKE% another

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I'm attempting to transfer between 2 tables, where one column is %LIKE% another.

In the table "juice" I have the fields title, brandid, and id.

In the table "brands" I have id and title.

The title field from juice will always contain an exact match to the title in brands - along with some other strings.

So I'm trying to check whether brands.title is %LIKE% juice.title, and if so put brands.id in the juice.brandid field.

This is what I have currently:

```
INSERT INTO juice(brandid) 
SELECT id FROM brands 
WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', @juice.title, '%')
```

Comment: Is this a stored procedure? Remember MySQL can't combine strings with `+`, you must use [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

Comment: Not a stored procedure, have updated with suggested and not getting the errors anymore but 0 rows change.

Comment: Does the `SELECT` give any results when run in isolation? Is `@juice.title` actually something that works? E.g. does `SELECT @juice.title` give you the value you're expecting? `@juice` is something you'd tend to see in a stored procedure, that means "variable", which is why I asked about stored procedures.

Comment: No so I guess this is part of the problem, I really just want to refer to the title column in the juice table there.

Comment: If you're trying to insert all non-matching values you probably need to do a `SELECT brands.id FROM brands RIGHT JOIN juice ON brands.title LIKE CONCAT('%', juice.title, '%')` instead but that's just a wild stab at solving this problem.

Comment: This actually seems much closer! How would I do the reverse and instead insert the matching values? At the moment I get 8000 or so non matching.

Comment: "How would I do the reverse and instead insert the matching values?" ?? You have a WHERE filter so you are selecting matching values??

Comment: I'm not sure if you need INSERT or UPDATE, what is the task that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to find all rows for title in brand that are %like% a a row in juice(title), then for each match set the id field from the brands table into the brandid field in the juice table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds more like you want an `UPDATE` instead of an `INSERT`. See if

```
UPDATE juice
       SET brandid = (SELECT brands.id
                             FROM brands
                             WHERE brands.title LIKE concat('%', juice.title, '%');
```

works for you. Note, that this requires, that only one row from `brands` matches. If more rows match you need to additionally define which one is the right one.